# Exception while reading properties of SMIME encrypted email

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, smime

I'm using Outlook 2019 add-in. I need to get mail item when it is moved to Sent items folder after the email is sent. I often send SMIME encrypted or signed and encrypted emails.
When I send encrypted or signed and encrypted email to most of the recipients then I can read mail item properties (using Outlook Object Model) without problem. MessageClass in such case is IPM.Note.
However I noticed that if I send encrypted or signed and encrypted email to myself (the same email in From and To) then I can't read almost all properties. I can read some like Class, DownloadState, IsConflict, MarkForDownload, Permission, Sent, Subject, Submitted, Unred or MessageClass which in this case is IPM.Note.SMIME but for others I get exception: "Your Digital ID name cannot be found by the underlying security system."
My cert is valid and seems to be ok as encrypted emails can be sent to me from another account.

Is it Outlook bug or I can do something to make Outlook read those properties using Outlook Object Model?

I also tried to use Extended MAPI and this time I could successfully read all properties. However I prefer to use OOM and I'm also curious why I can't read all properties using OOM only in specific case.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you manually open the encrypted message in Outlook?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What code do you use in your add-in for dealing with encrypted items? Is there any difference when you open such items manually and programmatically in Outlook?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko No, I don't get error and I can read properties.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I want to read MailItem properties after the item is sent and added to Sent items (so to be more specifc I use Items.ItemAdd event of Sent items folder and read item properties in that event's handler). In most cases Outlook seems to treat the item as normal email (IPM.Note) and I have access to properties but for some reason Outlook handles the item in a different way if I send the email to myself.
If I open the email in new inspector (Item.Open) I can read its properties.